# How to subset rows with an OR condition in Julia DataFrames

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I have a DataFrame and I want to filter the rows where column `During_Cabg` OR column `During_Pci` have a value of 1. Here's what I'm doing:

```
pci_or_cabg = @chain df begin
    select([:During_Cabg, :During_Pci] .=> ByRow(x -> coalesce.(x, 0)); renamecols=false)
    subset(:During_Cabg => ByRow(==(1)), :During_Pci => ByRow(==(1)))
end
```

The problem is that this line: `ByRow(==(1)), :During_Pci => ByRow(==(1)` seems to imply an AND not OR. The result I'm getting is values where BOTH columns are 1 (not what I want).

How to subset a DataFrame with multiple conditions (AND or OR) with multiple columns?

Thank you!

Comment: `df[(df.During_Cabg .== 1) .| (df.During_Pci .== 1), :]` works! :-)

Comment: Thank you Mark. It does work but I was looking for an idiomatic way to do it in a DataFrames.jl chain

Comment: you could use `filter([:During_Cabg, :During_Pci] => (c, p) -> (c == 1) | (p == 1), df)`

Comment: or `@chain df begin
    select(:During_Cabg, :During_Pci)
    subset([:During_Cabg, :During_Pci] => ByRow((c, p) -> (c == 1) | (p == 1)))
end
`

Comment: Thank you Mark. This works and I like to use subset instead of filter to stay consistent with the other DataFrames.jl functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `subset` AND condition is used. If you want to use OR you need to pass it in a single condition. A general way to do it would be:

```
subset(df, AsTable(columns) => ByRow(x -> any(predicate, x)))
```

or

```
subset(df, columns => ByRow((x...) -> any(predicate, x)))
```

if you want to apply the same predicate to all `columns`.

If you want a shorter syntax consider using one of the meta-packages, for example with DataFramesMeta.jl you can write):

```
@rsubset(df, :During_Cabg == 1 || :During_Pci == 1)
```

which works nice with chaining.

Comment: Thank you Bogumil! Exactly what I was looking for. Congratulations on the Julia for Data Analysis book!